# Infinite loop in quicksort alogrithm

Tags: javascript, quicksort

I'm wondering why i'm hitting an infinite loop in my recursive quick sort algorithm
 when I try to run the return statement `return (quicksort(less).concat([swapPos], quicksort(more))` it enters an infinite loop.

http://jsbin.com/uMAmIXA/1/edit

```
var quicksort = function (array) {
    //base case

    if (array.length <= 1) {
        return array;
    }

    var pivot = Math.floor(((array.length - 1) / 2));
    console.log(pivot);
    var swapPos = array[pivot];
    console.log(swapPos);
    var less = [];
    var more = [];

    array = array.slice(0, swapPos).concat(array.slice(swapPos + 1));
    // console.log(array);
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] < swapPos) {
            less.push(array[i]);
        } 
        else {
            more.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    //console.log(more);
    //  console.log(less);
    // return (quicksort(less).concat([swapPos], quicksort(more)));
};

quicksort([19, 12, 44, 2, 1, 7, 85, 22, 5, 4, 3]);
```

Comment: What does Mr.Debugger say?

Comment: I'm not sure how to debug an infinite loop since it freezes my browser

Comment: Try to alert the value as it stop loop.

Comment: May I ask you you aren't using the built in [sort](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11)?

Comment: @some I was just trying to do some time based tests on quicksort vs mergesort, nothing serious just for my own amusement

Comment: In your for-loop where you place them in `less` and `more`, you get an infinite loop with value 2 and 3, because when it tries to sort `more`, they will both end up in `more`, and then it will try again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array = array.slice(0,swapPos).concat(array.slice(swapPos+1));
```

I think this should be pivot rather than swapPos. Plus, I think you should exchange their names.